# How do you breed a "Seasonal" Dragon

Tags: dragonvale

I see from the marketplace that you can now breed a new dragon called a "Seasonal" dragon, which also seems to have a unique habitat.  What breeding combination is best to get this dragon?  What is the breeding time?  Also, is this dragon "limited"?

Comment: And what about the 'Other hemisphere' one mentioned in the description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to breed the Seasonal Dragon
>
> The Seasonal Dragon is seen to the eye as a four element but in fact it is actually three and may be even less! This 100% working breeding combination has been proven and confirmed by a long time DragonVale veteran that has been playing DragonVale since.. well the beginning of DragonVale!
>
> The required elements to breeding this Seasonal Dragon are Air, Fire, and Plant. This is not 100% certain if it is tri-element or dual-element yet but it definitely works and is the best breeding combination so far.
>
> To breed the Seasonal Dragon you must use a Blazing Dragon and a Plant dragon in your breeding island or breeding cave. Keep in mind that breeding this Seasonal Dragon does not matter in breeding left or right nor does the level. There is a higher chance of getting the Seasonal Dragon and rare dragons in the breeding island oppose to the breeding cave though.
>
> ---
>
> The breeding time is 48 hours.

Read more: http://www.gameteep.net/dragonvale-how-to-breed-seasonal-dragon-revealed/

Answer (score 0):

Blazing and plant will work the best

Comment: Hi, Jdog, welcome to Arqade!  Unfortuantely, you're not adding any information that hasn't already been said.  Do you have any new information for us?